# Equation type setting multiple equals

Tags: equations, arrows, greek, superscripts

what is wrong with this

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$$\phi\rightarrow\phi^'=\phi+\delta\phi=\phi+\Phi_\nu\omega^\nu$$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Replace `^'` by just a prime `'` (after phi). As a side note, replace `$$...$$` by `\[...\]`.

Comment: `^'` should just be `'`  and if it is latex `$$` should be `\[\]`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}` to form a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.   You may wish to see [Why is \[ … \] preferable to $$ … $$?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/106162) which recommends `\[` and `\]` as the preferred start/end display math.

Answer (score 1):

Your questions is not very clear about what you need and there is no minimal working example. However, I assume you are asking why the latex line doesn't compile inside a document? I must admit I don't exactly know *why* the syntax `$x^'$` doesn't work, but I do know that the following *does* work:

```
$$\phi\rightarrow\phi^{'}=\phi+\delta\phi=\phi+\Phi_\nu\omega^\nu$$
```

giving

[image: Dash as superscript]

or

```
$$\phi\rightarrow\phi'=\phi+\delta\phi=\phi+\Phi_\nu\omega^\nu$$
```

giving

[image: Normal dash]

The second option is the standard way to denote a modified variable (i.e. no need for the dash being a superscript).

I hope this solves your problem!

Comment: Yes, `^` does expansion and so the apostrophe isn't a “single token”.

Comment: please edit the answer to remove the suggestion of `^{'}` which removes the error message but makes the wrong output as it is `^{^{\prime}}` so a scriptscript style prime.

Comment: You should also avoid using `$$...$$` in a LaTeX document: see [Dai Bowen’s comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/342883/equation-type-setting-multiple-equals#comment841528_342883) to the question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: the question author didn't specify that they didn't want a superscript. I did not want to assume that they wanted just the prime, so I gave both options. Note that I did comment on the fact that standard usage is just the `'`.
@GustavoMezzetti: again, that's not what the questions was about so I did not address that. In fact, I would recommend using `\begin{equation}`, `\end{equation}` instead of `\[` and `\]`, unless you know you will not need any equation numbering anywhere in the doc.

Comment: @Wolfgang do you think it possible that anyone would want a super-superscript here?  It seems reasonable to assume that the OP thought that `x^{'}` would give a superscript prime not what it does give which is `x^{^{\prime}}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, it may be reasonable to assume so, I guess it's a judgement call. I just wanted to cover my bases.